# Hierarchy between post types

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical

So I'm working on a Wordpress site for a school. I have a page called "Faculty Staff Directory" and I also have a custom type called "Staff", with teacher profiles.

I've enabled the "staff" post type to be hierarchical. However, in the admin I'm only to create hierarchical within pages of the same post, not share it across other post types.

Is there a way to accomplish this or is this a Wordpress limitation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how the hierarchical setting works. Post types are independent entities. You can't mix and match them just like you can make a "Post" the child of a "Page" or the other way around.

So...

> Is there a way to accomplish this or is this a Wordpress limitation?

This is intentional behavior. I wouldn't call that a "limitation". Honestly, if you are mixing multiple post types I don't see the point of having multiple post types.

You will have to crawl the WordPress Plugin repo or write your own code for this, which I expect will be a *big* project, which would make it "work for me for free" and off-topic here. The ["Posts 2 Posts" plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) might do what you need. I have never used the plugin but it appears to be pretty solid. I don't recall ever seeing a complaint about it and I do recall seeing many recommendations.